# Verificar existencia BD y tabla en Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Como puedo comprobar la existencia de una tabla de la bd sqlite en una app de Android ?

```
  SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ruta_base_de_datos, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Comment: *Que es la existencia: el hecho de vivir o el hecho de entender nuestra consciencia?* Na, en serio, has de explicar mejor lo que quieres, mostrar lo que has intentado y tu problema: te da errores de compilacion/ejecucion? no encuentra tablas que si estan?  Mira [ask]  para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: amigo, edita la pregunta y coloca el codigo, Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ¿Como saber si la base de datos existe?.

Para esto necesitas saber el path en donde realizaste la creación de la base de datos, y usar este método, el cual intenta la conexión para determinar si existe en realidad.:

```
private boolean checkDataBase(String Database_path) {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Database_path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "No existe la base de datos " + .getMessage());
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}
```

#### ¿Como saber si la tabla de una Base de datos SQlite existe ?

Para eso puedes usar este método el cual busca el registro de la tabla dentro de la tabla `sqlite_master` y comprueba si existe mediante el nombre:

```
public boolean isTableExists(String nombreTabla) {
    boolean isExist = false;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '" + nombreTabla + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            isExist = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return isExist;
}
```

Comment: Diste con lo que buscaba, probaré el código ahora en cuanto pueda, gracias

Comment: como puedo hayar la ruta de la bd, m imagino que la qu se encuentra en data>nombrepaquete>database nosera.....

Comment: si asi intancio la base de datos **CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper carteraHelper = new CarteraSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "cartera", null, 1);** la Database_path sera cartera? @Jorgesys

Comment: La clase que extiende SQLiteOpenHelper es la que crea la base datos regultarmente, puedes usar el método .getPath() de la instancia de base de datos por ejemplo db.getPath();
/data/data/com.paquete.aplicacion/databases/myDatabase.db @EduardoMéndez